# Fastest way to transfer funds from Ethereum address to Bitcoin address

Tags: transactions, address, ethereum, money-transfer

I have an Ethereum address with some Ether in it, and I would like to transfer some of those funds to a Bitcoin address.

I am wondering what's the quickest and most painless way to perform the token exchange and the transaction - possibly without having to install a wallet client.

Comment: Although you may not realize it, what you are asking is for is effectively a service review.  Unfortunately, this is off-topic in this forum.  I'm sure you can find plenty of reviews for crypto-exchanges elsewhere, but this site is for questions with less opinion-based answers, and questions whose answers will remain relevant as various exchanges/services come in and out of existence.

Answer (score 0):

Use an exchange that trades both BTC & ETH.
Bittrex, ShapeShift, Coinbase, Poloniex, etc.